# Why doesn't this type for GUID in TypeScript behave as expected?

Tags: typescript, guid, typescript-template-literals

I am trying to make a type for GUID in TypeScript and while this looks like it should enforce hex strings divided with "-", it does not.

```js
type GUID = `${HexString<8>}-${HexString<4>}-${HexString<4>}-${HexString<4>}-${HexString<12>}`;

type HexString<N extends number> = string & {
  readonly length: N;
} & (LowercaseLettersOnly<string> | DigitOnly<string>);

type LowercaseLettersOnly<T extends string> = T extends `${infer U}${infer R}` ? (U extends LowercaseLetter ? LowercaseLettersOnly<R> : never) : T;

type LowercaseLetter = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f';
type DigitOnly<T extends string> = T extends `${infer U}${infer R}` ? (U extends Digit ? DigitOnly<R> : never) : T;

type Digit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f';
```

Expected to throw an error for any string different that a valid GUID

```js
const testGuid: GUID = 'e1b53ee5-4e77-4885-9fb1-e54921d9d87f';  // valid

const testGuid: GUID = 'abcdd-efggh-ijkgl-mndop-qrstuvwx1234';  // For some reason doesn't throw an error
```

Comment: You can see [in a playground](https://tsplay.dev/w22Vxw) the resulting type is just `\`${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}-${string}\``.

Comment: It doesn't work because ① `string` isn't treated like a union of every possible string literal; distributive conditional types don't distribute over `string`, so `LowercaseLettersOnly<string>` and `DigitOnly<string>` are just `string`. ② string literal types don't have a strongly typed `length` property (see [ms/TS#34692](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34692)) so, e.g., `"9999"` does not match `{length: 4}`

Comment: ③ Even if `type X = string & {length: 4}` worked, template literals won't respect branded strings, see [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/52836#pullrequestreview-1344374725), so `\`${X}\`` is just `string` and your whole thing is just "something with at least four dashes in it".  ⊛ There are so many ways this doesn't work that I'm thinking the question should be [edit]ed to be more focused. Instead of asking why the whole thing doesn't work, pick one broken piece (e.g., `DigitOnly<string>`) and ask about that. Then we can answer it directly.